# how to use linux crontab command

Tags: linux, shell, cron, command-prompt

I am new to linux crontab command and i found this explanation about the command in the web

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

according to this description, day of month and day of week are conflicting arguments. if i say every day of week and then i specify a specific day in the month then it is conflicting. so my question is why people have put day of week and day of month parameters in to this.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: it will execute both every day in the week you specified and one shot execution on that specific day of month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the requirement is often to run a program on each Monday, for instance, or on each 1st of month.